# Could not understand the output of this neural network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have given an input array(3000,1) and the output i expect is a multi - probability of 0,1,2.
i have scaled my inputs between 0 and 1 then why is my output coming over 1 and what are those hyphenated numbers along with it .

enter code here

```
training_input, training_label = shuffle(training_input, training_label)

# training_input range from 1-100 so we scale it down to between 0-1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_training_input = scaler.fit_transform(training_input.reshape(-1, 1))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

```
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXEmG.png
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements of output array are the **probabilities** of the instance to belong to class 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

To make the prediction you will have to go with the class with **highest** probability.

The hyphens represent negative powers, i.e. 9.99e-01 is 0.999
Therefore all the numbers are less than one and their sum is one.

To round:

```
import numpy as np
pred = (np.random.rand(27) ** 5).reshape(-1,3) #sample output
np.round(pred, 2) #rounds to show only a few decimals
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me how to remove those negative powers and just show them as 0.999 not with their negative powers, because ive used this code with 2 classes before and it didnt show the negative powers but only the probability of the classes like 0.95

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 0):

The activation function softmax is in exponential form. So your output will exceed 1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Softmax activation will output one value for each node in the output layer. The output values represent probabilities of the instance belonging to each of those classes respectively and those values always sum to 1.0.   
softmax(Z1) = exp(Z1) / [exp(Z1) + exp(Z2) + exp(Z3)]. Therefore, softmax function is always less than (or equal to) 1.